# How to setup a rounded button in SASS with Ionic Framework icons?

Tags: css, sass, ionic-framework

I'd to like to setup a rounded button with an ionic icon in the center.

I have something like that:

```
button {
    color: white;

    &.button-rounded {
        display: block;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        border: 2px solid white;
        border-radius: 50%;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

And the html:

```
<button class="button button-clear icon ion-home button-rounded"></button>
```

But the result is something like that:

[image: Rounded button]

Any help, please?

Comment: Can you create a Codepen.io demo out of it?

Comment: The true is I never used Codepen.io before...:-(

Comment: No problem, you just need to replicate your issue through a demo. You can use the snippet here or JSfiddle or whatever is easier for you.

Comment: Not using sass: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGpGPg

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the font size of the icon which is bigger than the rounded button. You can reduce the font-size to 24px and line-height to the same value in order to fit the icon exactly inside the circle. Increased the specificity of the overriding selector to avoid `!important`

```
.bar .buttons .button.button-icon .icon::before, .bar .buttons .button.button-icon::before, .bar .buttons .button.button-icon.icon-left::before, .bar .buttons .button.button-icon.icon-right::before {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

[**Updated Codepen**](http://codepen.io/Manojkr/pen/KdWdgo)

**SASS version:**

```
.bar .buttons .button.button-icon {
  .icon::before, &::before, &.icon-left::before, &.icon-right::before {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example using SASS, please? Is not working for me in SASS. The ideal solution for me would be create a new class I believe. I don't want all the right buttons of the header to be rounded.

Comment: Yes, assign a new class to not effect other buttons.

Comment: I've tried to create a new class without success, its why I am asking here in stackoverflow. Your solution is not working in my case. :-'(

Comment: It works in my Codepen link. Create your latest version along with my code to check what is not working.

Comment: Your solution is making all the buttons in the header more small :-( Look your codepen...

Comment: Yes, that's the only solution. Either you need to increase the bar height and button height or decrease the size of icons.